# dotted line for curve object

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am still a new user of Blender.

I am trying to map a ground polygon with dotted taxi line but the line are not in similar length. This only occur for curved mesh lines. Example are as follow:

[image: Dotted Line with un-similar length]
[image: Circle line with unsimilar length lines]

Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem (or question) is. Please edit it and try to make it clearer.

Comment: This is a known limitation of Blender curve system and its automated UV coordinates . To fix it properly you would have to convert your curve to a mesh and unwrap it manually